# Prevent encoding in @FormUrlEncoded retrofit

Tags: spring, retrofit

I need to make a post request such that the json data passed, has key pair value,where the key is data.
For example, if i use jquery as below, data is the key.
`$.ajax({
url: “/hello",
data:{ data: JSON.stringify(dataObject) },
type:"POST",
dataType:"json"
});`

which is equivalent to 
data:{ data: {“firstName”:”john”,"lastName”:”doe”}}.

I am using java spring retrofit, to accomplish the similar. In order to pass the key, i am using `@FormUrlEncoded and @Field("data") TypedString userInfo`

My retrofit interface is as below
 
    `public interface userInfoService {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST(“/hello")
         public Response userInfo(@Field("data") TypedString userInfo);`

where TypedString is {"firstName":"john","lastName":"doe"}

However, the request looks something like this

data=%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22john%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22doe%22%7D, since it form url encoded.The 3 party api can see the data key, but since it has "=" instea of ":", it cant be parsed

How, do i get the request to avoid = and actually send a decoded request.

I have also tried to use @Body instead of @FormUrlEncoded and @Field. Where @Body has TypedString as {data: {“firstName”:”john”,"lastName”:”doe”}}, but for some reason the 3 party api is not able parse the data key.